# Basic way of sending HTTP/POST in Haskell using http-conduit

Tags: http, haskell, post, functional-programming, network-programming

I'm trying to learn how to send simple string via HTTP/POST using Haskell and `http-conduit` (so that it works with https as well), reading the target url from a file, but it still seems all a bit overwhelming to me.

Basically the equivalent of what I learned to do with Racket here:
[Sending HTTP POST in Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236374/sending-http-post-in-racket)

Could someone give me a small or most basic example of doing this?

I tried reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/13465653/5083453

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure! The weird Haskell thing here to note is Haskell's record system. When you call `parseUrl` with a URL string, `http-conduit` is giving you back a `Request` record with some default values filled out, but the library expects you to fill out the rest.

For example, `parseUrl` always returns a `Request` with the HTTP method set to GET. It's up to us to overwrite that value by using the record update syntax – the thing where you append curly braces with new keys and values.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Lib where

import Data.Aeson
import Network.HTTP.Client

buildRequest :: String -> RequestBody -> IO Request
buildRequest url body = do
  nakedRequest <- parseRequest url
  return (nakedRequest { method = "POST", requestBody = body })

send :: RequestBody -> IO ()
send s = do
  manager <- newManager defaultManagerSettings
  request <- buildRequest "http://httpbin.org/post" s
  response <- httpLbs request manager
  let Just obj = decode (responseBody response)
  print (obj :: Object)
```

If you run this in GHCi, you should be able to send POSTs to httpbin:

```hs
λ> :set -XOverloadedStrings
λ> send "hello there"
fromList [("origin",String "<snip>")
         ,("args",Object (fromList []))
         ,("json",Null)
         ,("data",String "hello there")
         ,("url",String "http://httpbin.org/post")
         ,("headers",Object (fromList [("Accept-Encoding",String "gzip")
         ,("Host",String "httpbin.org")
         ,("Content-Length",String "11")]))
         ,("files",Object (fromList []))
         ,("form",Object (fromList []))]
```

You'll also need the OverloadedStrings extension. Without it, two things will happen:

- `nakedRequest { method = "POST" }` won't typecheck because the library expects a (strict) `ByteString` from the `bytestring` library. By default, `"POST"` and all string literals have type `String` a.k.a `[Char]`. While there is a function called `pack` that takes `String` and returns `ByteString`, it's much simpler to turn on overloaded strings. The compiler automatically calls `pack` on your behalf. There's more to it than that; see [Oliver's blog post](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-17-overloaded-strings.html) for the nitty gritty details.
- Another expression that won't typecheck is `send "hello there"`. `send` expects a `RequestBody`. And while again there's a function somewhere that would have type `String -> RequestBody`, it's much easier to turn on overloaded strings and have the compiler call it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes a lot more sense now. Just got another question about this: Why is it required to use Overloaded Strings, or asked differently: What do they do?

Comment: Thank you again, this helped a lot, I got one last question: I modified your example so it takes the url it is supposed to post to as a String `send :: RequestBody -> String -> IO ()` and tried to write another function which takes a random text from a file and sends it. I got the line `q <- rndPick $ lines qs` inside it, then `send q ur` in the last line, this gives me the error `Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `RequestBody'`. I assume that I am supposed to pack my String to a RequestBody in this situation, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes. In that case, you'll need to pack the string into a bytestring and then wrap the bytestring with one of [these RequestBody constructors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.24/docs/Network-HTTP-Client-Internal.html#t:RequestBody).